# Need Steps for authentication using AAD with Webapp at front and an API behind API Management

Tags: azure, architecture, azure-active-directory

I have a Webapp which authenticates via its own code, now i want this Webapp to call an API using Webapp/application identity , API is to be behind an API Management instance.

How do i secure this flow.

webapp --> APIM --> backend API

Comment: your question is just not clear. you need to give more details as to what you are trying to do here.

Comment: If you are wanted to authenticate your application with azure active directory for both client and API you azure would AD will manage everything for you. If you need this I can help how to figure it out.

Comment: Your web app probably would need to acquire an access token through client credentials flow and pass it along with the request + the subscription key for APIM. The API then can check the calling token has the necessary permissions.

Answer (score 0):

The article [Protect an API by using OAuth 2.0 with Azure Active Directory and API Management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-protect-backend-with-aad) walks through the steps to secure your Azure API management instances using Azure AD.

Do note that the steps for the older Azure Ad app registration portal, so do not try them in the new app registration portal (preview)